# Using sceneform sdk in a dynamic module results in crash

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, sceneform, dynamic-feature, dynamic-delivery

I am trying to use the sceneform sdk https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android in a dynamic module https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery. The application consists of primary app module and sceneform_dynamic_module. When the user clicks on Start Sceneform Activity, app attempts to download the sceneform dependency and launch an AR fragment.
However, I am facing below crash when trying to launch ArFragment that is present in dynamic module from the app module.

I have uploaded the github project at [here](https://github.com/mrunal-upadhyay/sceneform_dynamic_feature).

**Steps to reproduce the issue.** Get source code from [here](https://github.com/mrunal-upadhyay/sceneform_dynamic_feature) in Android Studio and follow below steps:

- ***Step1:*** Download bundletool from [here](https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases). Rename the jar to bundletool-all.jar
- ***Step2:*** Open terminal and change current working directory to the one containing the above jar. Run the below command: `alias bundletool='java -jar bundletool-all.jar'`
- ***Step 3:*** Generate App Bundle `./gradlew :app:bundleDebug`
- ***Step 4:*** Run bundletool to generate apks `bundletool build-apks --local-testing --bundle app-debug.aab --output app-debug.apks`
- ***Step 5:*** Connect device and install apks `bundletool install-apks --apks app-debug.apks`

Below is the crash that happens when tried to launch ArFragment from app module:

```
Invalid ID 0x00000000.2023-04-11 15:56:02.798 9148-9148 AndroidRuntime
com.acedev.dynamicfeature.debug
D Shutting down VM2023-04-11 E FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.acedev.dynamicfeature.debug, PID: 9148
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6 in
com.acedev.dynamicfeature.debug.sceneform_dynamic_module:layout/sceneform_ux_fragment_layout:
Binary XML file line #6 in com.acedev.dynamicfeature.debug.sceneform_dynamic_module:layout/sceneform_ux_fragment_layout:
Error inflating class
com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6 in
com.acedev.dynamicfeature.debug.sceneform_dynamic_module:layout/sceneform_ux_fragment_layout:
Error inflating class com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView
Caused by:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343 undefined)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858 undefined)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1010 undefined)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965 undefined)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127 undefined)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088 undefined)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686 undefined)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538 undefined)
at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.onCreateView(BaseArFragment.java:184 undefined)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963 undefined)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518 undefined)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282 undefined)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112 undefined)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647 undefined)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128 undefined)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072 undefined)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251 undefined)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502 undefined)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251 undefined)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1543 undefined)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8366 undefined)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3666 undefined)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:224 undefined)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:204 undefined)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176 undefined)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97 undefined)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2303 undefined)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106 undefined)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201 undefined)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288 undefined)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7884 undefined)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548 undefined)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936 undefined)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceTypeName(ResourcesImpl.java:281 undefined)
at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceTypeName(Resources.java:2319 undefined)
at com.google.ar.sceneform.utilities.LoadHelper.fromResource(LoadHelper.java:90 undefined)
at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Texture$Builder.setSource(Texture.java:153 undefined)
at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.PlaneRenderer.loadPlaneMaterial(PlaneRenderer.java:339 undefined)
at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.PlaneRenderer.(PlaneRenderer.java:84 undefined)
at com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView.initializeAr(ArSceneView.java:561 undefined)
```

Has anyone tried to use sceneform sdk in a dynamic feature module and able to successfully launch AR fragment from app module?